# How to enable scrolling with VerticalLayout in mobile flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

I use a VerticalLayout and there are many components inside, so the display does not show all of the items :

```
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:TextInput id="chp1" width="50%"/>
    <s:TextInput id="chp2" width="50%"/>
    <s:Button label="Enregistrer" click="enregistrer(event)" styleName="btn"/>
    <s:Button label="Lire" click="lire(event)" styleName="btn" />
    <s:TextArea id="area"/>
    <s:HGroup> 
        <s:Button label="Envoyer" click="send(event)" styleName="btn" />
        <s:Button label="Retour" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="btn" />
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:TextArea id="resultHTTP"/>
        ...
```

How to enable vertical scroll in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can never seem to get it to work unless I use this magic recipe:

```
<!-- Use size rules to set the upper limit in the bounding box with clipAndEnableScrolling -->
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <!-- Pin the scroller to the absolute bounds -->
    <s:Scroller top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0">
        <!-- The direction (vertical/horizontal) you want to scroll should                                  
            not  have an explicit bounds-->
        <s:Group width="100%">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5"
                                  paddingTop="5" verticalAlign="middle" />
            </s:layout>
            <!-- Scrollable content goes here -->
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Group>
```

The scroll bars will appear once the content gets to big for the visible area

Comment: why would you need scroll bar when contents can be visible withing the visible area in first place ?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. The contents may not be visible depending on the content and the screen size. In that case, you would want it to scroll instead of clip the contents or "leak" out of its container.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a [Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSb04c7610c3432839-13869d09121418556f1-7ffc.html) and wrap the viewport you want to scroll in one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic demonstration of how to add vertical scroll:

```
<s:Scroller height="100" width="100" verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
            <s:Group height="100%" width="100%">
                <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%">
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                    <mx:Button label="abcd"/>
                </mx:VBox>
            </s:Group>
        </s:Scroller>
```